# Append XML Node to Existing XML File

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have an XML in the following format

```
<Attachment>
 <AttachmentName>Top Nav Menu.docx</AttachmentName>
 <Subject>Attachment1</Subject>
 <Sender>JameelM@orioninc.com</Sender>
 </Attachment>
```

I want to attach another Attachment like above after the attachment close node. Below are the code that i have written for writing xml file

```
 var doc = new XDocument(

                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "true"),

                new XProcessingInstruction("test", "value"),

                new XElement("Attachment",new XElement("AttachmentName", attachment.Name),
                                          new XElement("Subject", exchangeEmailInformation.Subject),
                                          new XElement("Sender", exchangeEmailInformation.Sender
                                          )));
            doc.Save(ConfigInformation.BackUpPath + FolderId[index]+"\\Attachments"+index+".xml");
```

Comment: Attachment is a root node of your xml. You want to have several root elements?

Comment: No Root Element. I need to append a new Attachment like the xml format i have shared after the closing attachment node

Comment: Well LINQ to XML's `XDocument` is meant to operate on what the XML specification defines as a well-formed document. One of the well-formedness requirements is a single root element containing all other elements. Thus if you want to have two top level `Attachment` element nodes you want to construct something that is not an XML document and can't be represented by `XDocument`. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: is need to add a root element for this?

Comment: If you are going to have repeating elements, a parent node e.g. Attachments is a really good idea, given you apparently want to repeat the root element, even if it worked it wouldn't be valid xml anymore.

Comment: Yes. I want to add repeating element. Only inside the text is change

Answer (score 3):

Create root node for your attachments:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "true"),
    new XProcessingInstruction("test", "value"),
    new XElement("Attachments", 
        new XElement("Attachment", 
            new XElement("AttachmentName", attachment.Name),
            new XElement("Subject", exchangeEmailInformation.Subject),
            new XElement("Sender", exchangeEmailInformation.Sender)
    )));
```

When you decide to append another attachment, load document and add attachment to root:

```
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Attachment",
    new XElement("AttachmentName", attachment.Name),
    new XElement("Subject", exchangeEmailInformation.Subject),
    new XElement("Sender", exchangeEmailInformation.Sender)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the XMLSerializer class. There you can handle your XML files just as if they are classes. Just have a look, you will like it :)

Load XML -> Use Classes in Code (modify, delete, add) -> Serialize back into XML